# Access embedded tableau a better way

Tags: javascript, php, tableau-api

I have an embedded tableau on my site. In order for users to interact with the embedded site I use JavaScript to create a pop up window that takes a generated token + url to log them in. Something such as

```
base_url = "www.companyurl.com/app/bacmonitor.jsp?ssotype=saml&appname=Tableau&newToken=<GENERATED_TOKEN>"
window.open(base_url, "Sign In", "width=1,height=1,left=375,top=330")
```

After the pop up window opens with the specific URL, the tableau server naturally creates cookies which allows users to access to embedded site.

Is there an alternative way to do this without using a pop up window?

Comment: Question is a little unclear. You looking to sign them in? SSO? Or skip the login if they already have a valid session? cURL can make a request with cookies, assume if valid cookie is sent then there is no redirect.

Comment: Apologies if I wasn't clear enough. I already have the token required to sign them in. The current way I sign them in is through a pop up window using JavaScript and the generated token. My question was, is there way to do this without a pop up window?

Comment: Can't you just send the token with whatever the request is to embed the tableau widget/page? Am I understanding you make two requests now? One to 'login' another for the "widget" (iFrame or how does it get embedded exactly?)

Comment: The embedded page is a iframe that is essentially a widget. The only request I make is creating a pop up window which logs them into the tableau server via base_url. The widget works after this process because after accessing the url, via the pop up window, a cookie is created called a "workgroup_session_id" for www.companytableauserver.com. That cookie tells the widget "you are already logged in" so it displays all the necessary information.

Comment: And, to beat a dead horse, you can't create this "workgroup_session_id" by including the token on the iFrame's (src) request? Would think they would simply redirect on their end.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Hence my ugly "pop-up window" workaround.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177684/discussion-between-ficuscr-and-thatsano).

Comment: What was the conclusion of this?